# Create a histogram filled using another variable in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, fill

I am working with a dataset that includes the age of some people. I am trying to create a histogram for the ages of the people with ggplot in which the colours of the bars of the histogram should depend on some predefined age intervals.

So for example imagine a dataset like this:

```
>X
   Age   Age2
   10    Under 14
   11    Under 14
   10    Under 14
   13    Under 14
   20    Between 15 and 25
   21    Between 15 and 25
   35    Above 25
```

I have tried to do something like this:

```
ggplot(X, aes(x = Age)) + geom_histogram(aes(fill = Age2))
```

But it displays the following error message:

> ```
> Error: StatBin requires a continuous x variable the x variable is discrete. Perhaps you want stat="count"?
> ```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: From the error message it seems like x (Age) isn't continuous. Try to change Age to as.numeric(Age).

Comment: Or `as.numeric(as.character(Age))` if `Age` is a factor!! See `str(X)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

plotted with ggplot2, corrected excessive capitalization.

```
age <-c(10,11,10,13,20,21,35)
age2<-c(rep("Under 14", times=4), rep("Between 15 and 25",times=2),"Above 25")
X<-as.data.frame(cbind(age,age2))
X$age<-as.numeric(age)
X
names(X)
summary(X)
p<- ggplot(X, aes(x = age))+
  geom_histogram(aes(fill = age2))
p
```

[image: sample output]